# No SSH password prompt

Tags: centos, ssh, openvz

I'm trying to reach Centos based VPS in OpenVZ.

User prompt goes well, but after I type username, press Enter no password prompt occurs and server drops connection by timeout in a few seconds.

Tried different ssh clients (Windows based).

And NO log records in `secure.log`! Even no connection initialization records at all!

Comment: We need more info. Can you connect with `ssh -v` and provide the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "ssh -v" to debug the connection. Add more "v"'s for more verbose output. 
If you are able to install strace on the server you could try to strace the sshd process side with "strace -p PID" command to see what exactly happens.

Comment: Should -v be added on client side?

Comment: yes, ssh -v user@host or ssh -vv user@host etc

Comment: You know, the trick is in the fact that my server works well for now. I can connect and no such errors occur. I've read about GSSAPI config options in `sshd_config` file and these options could affect ssh connection. What do you think about that?

Comment: We cannot judge without any log or ssh -v. Typical and default configuration should _never_ produce any errors like the one you had. Did you change anything in sshd config ? (please also check your local .ssh config as weel)